# Does the blank option only pop up on google spreadsheet when there is a blank cell when i want to filter?

Tags: google-sheets

Does the blank option only pop when there is a blank cell or what other way would i use too quickly identify a blank cell without having to check manually on spreadsheet.

I tried with a file that had a missing value and resolve that immediately i applied the filter function.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question. I think that it assumes some prior knowledge of what you are doing/trying to do. Would you please edit the question to explain what is meant by `blank option`? The question asks about `quickly identify a blank cell` but a cell may _appear_ to be blank without being "blank". at all. And would you please explain what is meant by: `a file that had a missing value and resolve that immediately i applied the filter function`. It would be helpful if you supplied sample data and an examples of successful outcomes.